CSS: Selector for element which contains user-selected-text
I like to have a CSS selector which applies to a DIV element which has inside at least one text part which is currently selected/marked by user.
How can this accomplished?
I think I need something like div:has(any-user-selected-text)
Thanks!

It would be nice to show the css/html snippet that you’re referring to. It’s also part of the rules

if possible using JS, you can detect the selection via JS and add the extra class name to the div element.

This isn't possible with CSS alone.
